# Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\CategoryItem

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

when i install Porto Theme ,
php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile

```
Fatal error:  During inheritance of Countable: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\CategoryItem::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /data/wwwroot/ www.com/app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/CategoryItem.php on line 136 in /data/wwwroot/www.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
```

Comment: Did you check to make sure you are using the latest version of their extension?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that extension `Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation` is not compatible with your PHP version (8.1). You can try to fix this extension with some local path or contact developer and ask to fix the issue.

Class `Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\CategoryItem` implements  `Countable` and method `count` should return `int`. The fix might be like

```php
// ...
    public function count(): int {
        // ... logic
        // maybe need to cast to int the result in output like
        return (int)$count;
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,problem have been solved.